# Get user's primary email address mysql php best practices

Tags: mysql

I have a user table and a contact info table so that each user can have multiple phone numbers and multiple email addresses.  Is there a standard way to set and retrieve their primary contact info?

"humans" table

```
ID | name
1  | John
2  | Joan
```

"human_contact" table

```
ID | contact_type | contact_info | user_id
1  | email        | john@a.com   | 1
2  | email        | johnny@b.net | 1
```

"tickets" table

```
ID | human_id | event_date
1  | 1        | 2017-08-01
```

if John usually uses johnny@b.net, how do I mark that row as his favorite and retrieve that one for most queries?

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN humans
ON tickets.human_id=humans.ID
LEFT JOIN human_contact
ON human_contact.human_id=humans.ID
WHERE tickets.ID='112'
```

Comment: What is in the tickets table?

Comment: @kbball , I edited above & added a "tickets" table :) thank you

Comment: So, how should we choose which contact_info to make the favorite?

Comment: @kbball that's part of what I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extra coloumn named as **fav** which will have boolean values. This can help you in first finding whether he has any fav using a check where fav==true, then going on with that contact_info , or if the user doesnt have any favourites, then go with your usual query.

That is,

```
if( query( fav==1 for atleast 1 tuple )){
     return tuple with fav==1;
else{
     query ( usual query to get contact_info );
     return query_result;
}
```

for more easier understanding.Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please put this in a complete query form? I don't understand tuple and I've never used if in a query